# How to set to breakpoint in the start of a function?

Tags: firebug

How to set to breakpoint in the start of a function given that I know only function name but don't know the file in which it is there?
If I know the file and line number then I can simply go there and set the breakpoint.
I've searched in internet but could not get the answer.

Comment: How many scripts is your page loading?  Can't you just search them for the function name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this aged and unanswered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374107/firebug-how-to-track-the-definition-of-a-called-function

Comment: My page has 15 .js files. How do I search the .js files for the function name? Even this would solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but try : debug(function) to set in breakpoint in a function.
You can find the function within .js files here: [Trying to locate function in JavaScript files using Firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753734/trying-to-locate-function-in-javascript-files-using-firebug)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you get the [Web Developer Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) to go along with FireBug. Install it, then go to *Web Developer* -> *Information* -> *View Javascript*. It will open a new tab, displaying all the javascript files (inline and included) on a single page. Happy searching!